# Apache on XAMPP , Tomcat 9 (not on XAMPP) HTTP PATCH 501 method not implemented

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets

here is my spec:

```
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
JAVA: JDK 11.0.2
Tomcat: 9.0.21
XAMPP: 7.2.22
```

I'm running a Servlet with tomcat 9, and I need to make this server receive HTTP PATCH method.
I'm using the packages below:

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;`

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;`

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;`

I overwrite `doPatch` method and try to make it work but in vain.

Any suggestions to make tomcat receive HTTP PATCH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an easy way to overcome it!

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   if ("PATCH".equals(request.getMethod())) 
        doPatch(request, response);
        return;
   }
   super.service(request, response); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how did you use it ?